# How to print palindroms of given list of words usinf FOR LOOP?

Tags: python, for-loop

I'am searching on the internet quite long but I'am not succesfull. I have a list of words:

```
words = ["kayak", "pas", "pes", "reviver", "caj", "osel", "racecar","bizon", "zubr", "madam"]
```

And I need to print only words that are palindromes. I found this solution:

```
words = ["kayak", "pas", "pes", "reviver", "caj", "osel", "racecar","bizon", "zubr", "madam"]

palindrome = list(filter(lambda x: (x == "".join(reversed(x))), words))
print(palindrome)
```

But I dont like it. I have to use FOR loop somehow and I dont know how. I tried many things but still dont get it.

Thank you.

Comment: You already have a working code. As a first step, why not convert the lambda into a for-loop?

Comment: You would probably find people more receptive to helping if you posted some (or even one) of the many things you've tried.

Comment: OK, next time. I will keep it in mind.

Comment: Thanks @enke for the idea - I will try to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the example with explanations:

```py
words = ['kayak', 'pas', 'pes', 'reviver', 'caj', 'osel', 'racecar','bizon', 'zubr', 'madam']

# Start with empty list
palindromes = []

# Iterate over each word
for word in words:
    # Check if word is equal to same word in reverse order
    is_palindrome = (word == word[::-1])

    # Append to results if needed
    if is_palindrome:
        palindromes.append(word)

print(palindromes)
# => ['kayak', 'reviver', 'racecar', 'madam']
```

Answer (score 1):

With a for loop:

```
palindrome = []
for i in words:
    if i == "".join(reversed(i)):
        palindrome.append(i)
print(palindrome)
```

Or list comprehension:

```
palindrome = [i for i in words if i == "".join(reversed(i))]
print(palindrome)
```

Output:

```
['kayak', 'reviver', 'racecar', 'madam']
```

Comment: Nice oneliner with the list comprehension one.